# Dynamic programming - determining the state

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, state, dynamic-programming

I've recently faced this problem in a dynamic programming curriculum, and I honestly have no idea about how to determine the appropriate state.

You're given **N** (1 <= N <= 70) paragraphs and **M** (1 <= M <= N) figures. Each paragraph **i** requires **PL_i** (1 <= PL_i <= 100) lines and references at most one figure. Each figure is referenced exactly once (i.e., no two paragraphs can reference the same figure, and for each figure there's a paragraph that references it.) Each figure requires **PF_i** (1 <= PF_i <= 100) lines.

The task is to distribute those figures and paragraphs on paper in the order they're given, where one paper fits for **L** lines at most. No paragraph or figure is too large to fit on one paper. If a paragraph **x** placed on paper **x_p** references a figure **y** then **y** must be placed on either the paper **x_p - 1** or **x_p** or **x_p + 1**.

We have to find the minimum number of lines (and thus pages) to allocate in order to distribute all the figures and paragraphs. Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The meaning of "in the order they're given" is crucial.  Is it acceptable for 2 paragraphs to appear on a page, with both their referenced figures appearing on the next (or previous) page?  If not (i.e. if every figure must immediately precede or follow its corresponding paragraph) then the problem is simpler.

Comment: @j_random_hacker nope, not necessarily. "In the order they're given" means that you can't have two paragraphs **a** and **b** such that **b** appears before **a** in the input, but is allocated in a paper after **a** in the final distribution.

Comment: Are you saying the answer to my "Is it acceptable..." question is "yes"?  (I understand that the output order of *paragraphs* must match the input order of paragraphs, but I'm not clear on whether the same is true for figures.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, the answer is yes :) As for the order thing, it applies on both paragraphs and figures.

Comment: Is it possible to split one paragraph on more pages?

Comment: Are you given which figure is referenced by which paragraph?

Comment: @tskuzzy Yes, of course.

Comment: Do you have any priority for inserting to x_p - 1 or x_p or x_p + 1 ?

Comment: @RuslanDzhabbarov No, we don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is in general problem that you have to redorder paragraps P and Figures P ether (P,F) order or (F,P) ordering.

Placing in document is (P1,F1),(P2,F2),(P3,F3) where each tuple (P,F) can be of any order (P,F) or (F,P) and there are some F-s that has length 0 what means there is no F.

Problem is to find ordering for each (P,F) pair.

One solution for finding least number of Paiges is applying this rule

```
lines_total = MIN(lines(P,F),lines(F,P)) + remaining() //this is custom addition
```

Ok, there is lack of prototype of this function, but for C goes like

```
calc_spend_lines(pfpairs * pairs)
```

Where pfpaires is

```
typedef struct
{
   int P;
   int F;
} pfpaires;
```

And you know that you reached end when P is 0 for instance.

All you have to do, is to make function, that implements that special + sign having in mind page breaks and dead lines.

This gives O(N) solution, for minimum over number of pages but not number of lines, since your ending condition will be 0.

If you want to minimise over number of lines you can use bisection where you set ending condition to something else instead of 0 and that gives you

O(N*log(L)) solution

**EDIT**
Since there can be other P inbetween current P and F, one just have to check instead of ((F,P),(P,F)) also check for blank page (N) so combos are ((P,F)(P,N,F),(F,P),(F,N,P)). **Conclusion is , that you end up more complicated algorithm, but same complexity.** Point is that once you check one of 4 ordering, there is only one trivial way to make optimal positioning, just current state (lines) is bit complicated.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly (see comments), a figure can be placed such that there are other paragraphs (possibly referencing other figures) between the figure and the paragraph referencing it, so you will need more than just the immediate (P, F) pairing

Comment: Thanks a lot ralu! Very thorough explanation and solution.

Comment: I'll award you the bounty in 6 minutes. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ralu: Statement -"Placing in document is (P1,F1),(P2,F2),(P3,F3) where each tuple (P,F) can be of any order (P,F) or (F,P) and there are some F-s that has length 0 what means there is no F." not right, since it's possible to have situation like (P1,P2),(F1,F2),(P3,F3) and (P1,F1,F3),(P2,P3),(F2), so finding minimum between (P,F) and (F,P) won't work. Plus, your solution won't find least number of pages since you are calculating lines total, but there is restriction: P can't be placed on 2 pages.

Answer (score 1):

As a DP state for current page P you can use an array (of size **L** * 2), indexed by the number of lines, reserved on page P for figures, referenced from page P+1 or (negated) number of lines, needed on page P+1 for figures, referenced from page P.

Each array element consists of two values:

1. **x** - the number of paragraphs, distributed on pages 1 .. P;
2. some data, needed to restore paragraphs/figures distribution after DP algorithm is finished.

Use this array to compute array for the next page (P+1). For each valid element of the array P, add new paragraphs (**x**+1, **x**+2, ...) to page P+1, updating correspondent elements of the array P+1. While it is possible, place figures, referenced by these paragraphs, on page P, then on page P+1, then on page P+2. Overwrite elements of the array P+1, having lower values of **x**, with higher values.

Time complexity of this algorithm is O(**L** * **N**): lines-per-page times number-of-paragraphs. Because processing each page is O(lines-per-page * average-paragraphs-per-page).

Answer (score 1):

Can be optimized, but it's working solution:

```
public class ParagraphsAndFigures {
```

```
        public static ArrayList<PageContent> generatePages(List<Paragraph> paragraphs, int L) {
            ArrayList<PageContent> pages = new ArrayList<PageContent>();
            for (int i = 0; i < paragraphs.size() * 2; i++) {
                pages.add(new PageContent());
            }
            int page = 0;

            for (Paragraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
                do {
                    int cur = pages.get(page).linesReserved;
                    int next = pages.get(page + 1).linesReserved;

                    if (cur + paragraph.size < L) {
                        cur += paragraph.size;

                        if (paragraph.figure != null) {

                            if (pages.get(page + 1).hasPicture()) {
                                if (next + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                    pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                    pages.get(page + 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                    pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                    pages.get(page + 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                    break; // next paragraph
                                } else {
                                    page++;
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }

                            if (pages.get(page).hasPicture()) {
                                if (cur + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                    pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                    pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                    pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                    pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                    break; // next paragraph
                                } else {
                                    if (next + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                        pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                        pages.get(page + 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                        pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                        pages.get(page + 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                        break; // next paragraph
                                    }
                                    page++;
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }

                            if (page != 0 && pages.get(page - 1).hasPicture()) {
                                int prev = pages.get(page - 1).linesReserved;
                                if (prev + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                    pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                    pages.get(page - 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                    pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                    pages.get(page - 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                    break; // next paragraph
                                } else {
                                    if (cur + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                        pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                        pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                        pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                        pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                        break; // next paragraph
                                    }
                                    if (next + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                        pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                        pages.get(page + 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                        pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                        pages.get(page + 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                        break; // next paragraph
                                    }
                                    page++;
                                }
                            }

                            if (page != 0) {
                                int prev = pages.get(page - 1).linesReserved;
                                if ( prev + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                    pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                    pages.get(page - 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                    pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                    pages.get(page - 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                    break; // next paragraph
                                }
                            }

                            if (cur + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                break; // next paragraph
                            }

                            if (next + paragraph.figure.size < L) {
                                pages.get(page).texts.add(paragraph);
                                pages.get(page + 1).texts.add(paragraph.figure);
                                pages.get(page).linesReserved += paragraph.size;
                                pages.get(page + 1).linesReserved += paragraph.figure.size;
                                break; // next paragraph
                            }
                            page++;
                        }
                    }
                    page++;
                } while (true);
            }
            return pages;
        }
    }
```

`And tests:

public class ParagraphsAndFiguresTest {
            @Test
            public void pageGeneration1() throws Exception {
                // given
                ArrayList paragraphs = new ArrayList();
                paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(20,21));
                paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(22,23));
                paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(24,25));`

`// when
            ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents = ParagraphsAndFigures.generatePages(paragraphs, 50);
            // then
            assertThat(transformToList(pageContents), is(asList("20", "21", "p0" ,"22" ,"23", "p1" ,"24" ,"25", "p2")));
        }

        @Test
        public void pageGeneration2() throws Exception {
            // given
            ArrayList<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(10,11));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(28,21));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(22,23));

            // when
            ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents = ParagraphsAndFigures.generatePages(paragraphs, 50);
            // then
            assertThat(transformToList(pageContents), is(asList("10", "11" ,"28", "p0" ,"21", "22" , "p1" ,"23", "p2")));
        }

        @Test
        public void pageGeneration3() throws Exception {
            // given
            ArrayList<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(10,11));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(12,30));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(13,19));

            // when
            ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents = ParagraphsAndFigures.generatePages(paragraphs, 50);
            // then
            assertThat(transformToList(pageContents), is(asList("10", "11" ,"12", "13", "p0" ,"30", "19" , "p1" )));
        }

        @Test
        public void pageGeneration4() throws Exception {
            // given
            ArrayList<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(10,11));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(30,12));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(13,16));

            // when
            ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents = ParagraphsAndFigures.generatePages(paragraphs, 50);
            // then
            assertThat(transformToList(pageContents), is(asList("10", "11" ,"12", "16", "p0" ,"30", "13" ,"p1" )));
        }

        @Test
        public void pageGeneration5() throws Exception {
            // given
            ArrayList<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<Paragraph>();
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(31,32));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(17,21));
            paragraphs.add(new Paragraph(30,35));

            // when
            ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents = ParagraphsAndFigures.generatePages(paragraphs, 50);
            // then
            assertThat(transformToList(pageContents), is(asList("31", "p0", "32", "17", "p1", "21", "p2", "30", "p3", "35", "p4")));
        }

        private List<String> transformToList(ArrayList<PageContent> pageContents) {
            List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < pageContents.size(); i++) {
                PageContent pageContent = pageContents.get(i);
                if (!pageContent.texts.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Text text : pageContent.texts) {
                        result.add(String.valueOf(text.size));
                    }
                    result.add("p"+i);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }`

And structures:

    public class PageContent {
        int linesReserved;
        Collection texts = new ArrayList();

public boolean hasPicture() {
        for (Text text : texts) {
            if (text instanceof Figure) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class Text {
    protected int size;
}
public class Figure extends Text{
}
public class Paragraph extends Text {

    public Paragraph(int size, int fSIze) {
        this.size = size;
        this.figure = new Figure();
        this.figure.size = fSIze;
    }

    Figure figure;
}

Answer (score -1):

At first I'd recommend to build recursive method.

Choose best from variants: start with paragraph or with figure.

At every step choose best from possible variants: add pagebreak, add next figure, add next paragraph. Simple state machine would help to eliminate prohibited variants (for example, 2 pagebreaks in row), but it is not necessary.

When recursive solution will be checked, you can transform it to top-down or bottom-up dynamic programming, as described in most of algorithmic courses concerning DP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think that the main issue is how to keep track what you "have done so far" -- in the recursive method you can keep the whole array of assigned paragraphs and figures, but in the DP solution you can't do that; there must be a trick to know what you need to analyze when calculating answers for larger states. Any ideas?

Comment: Make 2D table with some rows - paragraphs/state, and fill it from left to right. When you reach last column, you will have the best route through the table.